# Inserting accounts into Mirror API using service account returns "invalid_grant" error

Tags: .net, authentication, google-glass, google-gdk, google-mirror-api

I'm using the [Mirror API .NET Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Mirror.v1/) with a Google Service Account to do 3rd Party Authentication via the MyGlass app. I'm following the [Authentication for GDK Glassware](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/authentication) documentation to authenticate my users server-side and then insert the account.

When I try to insert a new account using the Mirror API, I get an OAuth Error:  "invalid_grant":

**Stack Trace:**

> Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponseException was unhandled
>   by user code   HResult=-2146233088   Message=Error:"invalid_grant",
>   Description:"", Uri:""   Source=Google.Apis
>
> at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.Execute() in
>   c:\code\google.com\google-api-dotnet-client\default_182\Tools\Google.Apis.Release\bin\Debug\output\default\Src\GoogleApis\Apis\Requests\ClientServiceRequest.cs:line
>   96\r\n

It's being unwrapped and thrown by the Execute() function in [ClientServiceRequest.cs](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Src/GoogleApis/Apis/Requests/ClientServiceRequest.cs). Line 96.

**Source Code:**

```
const string password = "notasecret";
X509Certificate2 certificateToExport = new X509Certificate2(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("/Path/To/Certificate.p12"), password, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
var rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)certificateToExport.PrivateKey;

// Have to export the provider or you get an "Invalid Algorithm" error when 
// trying to sign the request.
RSACryptoServiceProvider cryptoProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
cryptoProvider.ImportParameters(rsa.ExportParameters(true));

var serviceAccountCredential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(id: "MYCLIENTID.apps.googleusercontent.com")
{
Key = cryptoProvider,
Scopes = new List<string>() { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/glass.thirdpartyauth" },
User = "MYCLIENTID@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
});

var mirrorService = new MirrorService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() { HttpClientInitializer = serviceAccountCredential });
Account account = new Account() { AuthTokens = new AuthToken[] { new AuthToken() { AuthTokenValue = sessionKey, Type = "sessionKey" } } };

// Exception thrown here
Account insertedAccount = mirrorService.Accounts.Insert(account, userToken: userToken, accountType: "example.com", accountName: accountName).Execute();
```

Some things I've double and triple-checked:

- I have the correct client ID and email address.
- I have provided the scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/glass.thirdpartyauth.
- The userToken that was passed to me as a query parameter by the MyGlass app webview is provided *back* to the MirrorAPI.
- I'm signing the request with the certificate provided to me by Google.
- MyGlass is using the correct authentication redirect URL
- The [Google Analytics documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtAuthorization#helpme) says about an "invalid_grant" error:

> 1. Your server's clock is not in sync with NTP.
> 2. The refresh token limit has been exceeded.

Server clock is in-sync. This happens on multiple machines. Will investigate whether/how the token limit has been exceeded. I was under the impression that the API library would handle refreshes for me.

I feel I've completely mis-understood something (likely). I'd appreciate someone pointing out what I've got wrong here.

Comment: If this question requires further clarification, please let me know.

Comment: You do understand that a service account is its own entity, which means even if you could use a service account with the mirror api you would only manage to write to the service accounts glass timeline.   I don't think that the service account owns a pair of glass.  What exactly is it you are trying to do?

Comment: The account command lets you insert a new Account into the Account Manager on Glass.  You are logging in using a Service account.  What is it you are trying to do exactly.  More information needed.

Comment: Thanks DalmTo. I'm trying to insert an account into the mirror api so that I can retrieve the account on the set of glasses that authenticated when the app was installed in MyGlass. I'm following Google's documentation on this, which specifically says you should use a service account to do this. Granted the documentation could be wrong, but they've referred to it themselves throughout the approval process, so I'm pretty sure it's correct.

Comment: where is this documentation, you speak of?  I use Oauth2 for mine, I cant understand how they would think a service account would work. but this may just be something I haven't heard of.

Comment: Linked at the top of the question: https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/authentication

Comment: that's your probably that's only for applications installed on  glass. You cant install a .net application on to glass only android.

Comment: No it's specifically for running on server side apps. That's why it's a service account and not a client account.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59926/discussion-between-daimto-and-pabloc).

Comment: @PabloC, could you add more information in the chat?

Comment: @Alain I've updated the chat with a link to the logs you requested. Looks like you were right, the token appears to be invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [chat thread](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59926/discussion-between-daimto-and-pabloc), the issue was due to the Service Account authentication failing due to the wrong data being passed in the `ServiceAccountCredential` class.

The code snippet used in the original question should be fixed with:

```
var serviceAccountCredential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(id: "MYCLIENTID@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
{
    Key = cryptoProvider,
    Scopes = new List<string>() { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/glass.thirdpartyauth" }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've submitted your Glassware at https://developers.google.com/glass/distribute/form. Be sure to mention that you're wanting to add accounts as well, and give them the account type for your application. I recall having to do this on my application before I was able to add accounts. You'd think this would be in their documentation, but I don't believe it is.

Comment: Thanks Jessie. I've given google this information as part of getting the glassware listed store. They know I'm trying to do 3rd party auth.

Comment: Well, that's all I've got. I seem to recall having this same issue in Python, but I think mine was due to Python not liking the key format. My Python looks almost identical to you C#/.net code.

Comment: I appreciate it Jessie. You know I might have to try using a different language, maybe the JS library.